# Create compressed string in perl that can be uncompressed by php gzuncompress

Tags: php, perl

I need to create a compressed string using Perl that I can uncompress using PHP gzuncompress

I tried the following in Perl

```
use IO::Compress::Gzip qw(gzip $GzipError) ;
my $input  = 'THIS IS A TEST'; 
my $output;
gzip \$input => \$output;
```

but PHP cannot uncompress this

If I view the out from perl it is different than if I compressed it using PHP's gzcompress

Any help in solving this would be much appreciated

Comment: `gzcompress` uses `zlib`. You should look into http://perldoc.perl.org/Compress/Zlib.html instead.

Comment: I tried using Compress::Zlib; - $output = compress('THIS IS A TEST') - same problem :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `compress` function from [Compress::Zlib](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Compress-Zlib/lib/Compress/Zlib.pm#COMPRESS/UNCOMPRESS).

```
$ perl -MCompress::Zlib=compress -e 'print compress("Foo Bar\n")' | php -r 'echo gzuncompress(fgets(STDIN));'
```

Output:

```
Foo Bar
```

Comment: Thanks - I have now found why it wasn't working with compress - I had manged to pass it some extra data :( - now all working